# wifi disconnecting 15.04

Tags: wireless

I have problem with wifi disconnecting after a while. The only way to connect is to restart the laptop. Has been same on all versions of Ubuntu (currently 15.04). Information on wifi: "driver=rtl819xE driverversion=0014.0401.2010". Are there any solution to this?

Comment: Download the latest driver from http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=21&Level=4&Conn=3, install it and then report back.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/646476/146769) answer solves the problem. Me too was facing the same. Mine got fixed by

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

You can also update the driver as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/645472/146769), if it is required.